# The return value of "org.w3c.dom.Document.getDocumentElement()" is null

Tags: java, xml, w3c

I have this code

```java
DocumentBuilderFactory docb = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder dom = docb.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = dom.newDocument();
Element raiz = doc.createElement("Alumnos");
//-Problem here 
doc.getDocumentElement().appendChild(raiz);
```

This is supposed to create an XML file, but when I try to do it, I get an exception:

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException:
> Cannot invoke "org.w3c.dom.Element.appendChild(org.w3c.dom.Node)"
> because the return value of
> "org.w3c.dom.Document.getDocumentElement()" is null

I'm not sure why I get this and why the document element is null. Am I forgetting something?

I tried to create an XML file to append elements later, but I got that error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've created an empty document, it doesn't yet have a "documentElement", so `getDocumentElement()` returns `null`. The method `doc.createElement` just creates an element, it doesn't add it to the document, you need to do that explicitly:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory docb = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder dom = docb.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = dom.newDocument();
Element raiz = doc.createElement("Alumnos");
doc.appendChild(raiz);
```

In other words, remove the call to `getDocumentElement()`, but call `appendChild(raiz)` directly on `doc`. This will make `Alumnos` the document element (root element).

Afterwards, calls to `doc.getDocumentElement()` will return the same object as referenced by `raiz`.